# How to get the values of multiple context provider of the same context

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I have two context providers for the same context. The first provider provides many states and methods. But the second provider provides a relatively small state and methods. The first Provider wraps the second provider.
So components that are inside these two providers seem to only get the value provided by only the second provider. I was hoping if there is any way I could get states or methods which are not provided by the second, inner, provider but provided by the first, upper, component.

```
<ContextXProviderOne> // let say this provider provides only 10 states and 10 methods
<ContextXProviderTwo> // this provider provides only 3 states and 3 methods
  //
  //
  <SomeComponent /> 
  ...
  ...
  //
  //
</ContextXProviderTwo>
</ContextXProviderOne>
```

So in my case, I want components inside these two providers to access the 3 states and 3 methods found in ContextXProviderTwo and if the requested state or method do not found in the ContextXProviderTwo, I was hoping they could look for on the upper ContextXProviderOne.

Comment: Also why are u not wrapping all the states in one `Context.Provider` ?

Answer (score 3):

The React Context can hold only 1 value, using 2 Providers will cause the 2nd Provider to override the value that it provides child components.

According to the React docs:

> The Provider component accepts a value prop to be passed to consuming
> components that are descendants of this Provider. One Provider can be
> connected to many consumers. **Providers can be nested to override
> values deeper within the tree.**